# How to make sure GET is from my site?

Tags: ruby, ajax

I have a servlet respond to my GET request `'/getdata'`:

```
get '/getdata' do
  if request.referrer.to_s == '/my_website_uri'
    erb :content
  else
    reponse = [ 404, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, '<h1>404 - Not Found</h1>' ]
  end
end
```

I want to make sure if the request is by my page, then gives data, otherwise gives 404.

I have the code above. It checks the request referrer if it includes my URI, but I think anyone can mock a request like that...Is there any better ways?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You seem to be describing Servlet's job, but demonstrating it in Ruby code instead of Servlet code. What exactly do you have? Servlet calls Ruby and thus Ruby should do the check, or Ruby calls Servlet and thus Servlet should do the check?

Comment: *sidenote* : I don't normally give 404, which you can't differentiate between a file is really missing, or intent to do so. Consider using `403 Forbidden` or `401 Unauthorized`.

Comment: @BalusC It is a ruby servlet, not Java.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Thanks for the tip. I will use 401 in this case then.

Comment: @MattBall I don't know how you conclude that but I also have something similar to yours: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick/HTTPServlet/AbstractServlet.html

Comment: My mistake; I am obviously nowhere near as familiar with Ruby as Java. That said, [the term "servlet" pretty much universally refers to the Java flavor](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), and [particularly on SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby+servlets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [`referer` is trivial to spoof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing). No, there isn't a way that's both easy and secure.

You'd control access to that URL the same way you'd control access to any other: with your pick of authorization and authentication protocols – as straightforward as [HTTP basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_basic_authentication) (over SSL!), or as modern as [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oauth).